# Many-to-many relationship to determine if user has liked a post

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains all of the posts. I also have a table where a row is added when a user likes a post with foreign keys user_id and post_id.

I want to retrieve a list of **ALL** of the posts and whether or not a specific user has liked that post. Using an outer join I end up getting some posts twice. Once for user 1 and once for user 2. If I use a WHERE to filter for likes.user_id = 1 AND likes.user_id is NULL I don't get the posts that are only liked by other users.

Ideally I would do this with a single query. SQL isn't my strength, so I'm not even really sure if a sub query is needed or if a join is sufficient.

Apologies for being this vague but I think this is a common enough query that it should make some sense.

EDIT: I have created a DB Fiddle with the two queries that I mentioned. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oFM2zWsR9WFKTPJA16U1Tz/4

UPDATE: Figured it out last night. This is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT
posts.id AS post_id,
posts.title AS post_title,
CASE
WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM likes
  WHERE posts.id = likes.post_id
  AND likes.user_id = 1
) THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE END
  AS liked
FROM posts;
```

Although I was able to resolve it, thanks to @wildplasser for his answer as well.

Comment: Can you please provide more context/code snippets, for example for your model?

Comment: If you could provide an example, and maybe be more specific of how the result you want will have to be it would be good.

Comment: I have now updated with a DB Fiddle that contains the schema and two queries that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data (I needed to change it a bit, because one should not assign to serials):

---

```
 CREATE TABLE posts (
  id serial,
  title varchar
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial,
  name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE likes (
  id serial,
  user_id int,
  post_id int
);

INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES ('First Post');
INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES ('Second Post');
INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES ('Third Post');

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Obama');
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Trump');

INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (2, 2);
```

---

```
-- I want to retrieve a list of ALL of the posts and whether or not a specific user has liked that post
SELECT id, title
        , EXISTS(
                --EXISTS() yields a boolean value
                SELECT *
                FROM likes lk
                JOIN users u ON u.id = lk.user_id AND lk.post_id=p.id
                WHERE u.name ='Obama'
                ) AS liked_by_Obama
FROM posts p
        ;
```

---

Results:

---

```
 id |    title    | liked_by_obama 
----+-------------+----------------
  1 | First Post  | t
  2 | Second Post | f
  3 | Third Post  | f
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser. Figured it out last night. I used a slightly different query. I'll add it to my post. I only assigned to serials for the fiddle, otherwise I wouldn't have done that.

Comment: My point is: you dont need the `CASE...END`, since the resulting value  from  EXISTS() **is** a boolean value.

Comment: For sure, I haven't loaded this in to my app yet. I think with the `CASE...END` you would be able to define what value you want to use when it exists and when it doesn't. The `EXISTS()` is cleaner if a bool is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have two tables such as post table which includes all post from different users and a like table with `user.id` and `post id`. if you want to retreive only posts then

```
select * from posts
```

if you need user information as well, which is present in `user` table then you can do below.

```
select user.user_name, post.postdata from user,post where post.userid=user.userid
```

in above query, `user_name` is a column name in `user` table and `postdata` is a column in `post` table.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will put together a fiddle example and edit my post.