# Annotate an `exists` subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a simple news app where users can see latest posts and they can like some of these posts.

The models:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

from app import db


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    ...

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    body = db.Column(db.String)
    ...

class Like(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    post_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Post.id))
    post = relationship(Post, backref=backref('likes'))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get each post with an additional field that indicates whether the post is liked by the logged in user or not but in an optimized way without making a query for each post.

I tried to do this is the schema level, using `marshmallow-sqlalchemy`:

```py
from marshmallow import fields

from app import ma
from news.models import Post

class PostSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    is_liked = fields.Method("get_is_liked")

    def get_is_liked(self, obj):
        user = self.context['user']
        return bool(Like.filter_by(user_id=user.id, post_id=obj.id).first())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

But this would result an N queries for each post.

I also tried to implement this like the annotations in Django ORM:

```py
class PostListView(Resource):

    # I have the user object here using a decorator
    def get(self, user):
        # I know that this is a bad syntax
        query = Post.query(Post.likes.filter_by(user_id=user.id).exists().label('is_liked')))

        schema = PostSchema(strict=True, many=True, context={"user": user})
        result = schema.dump(query.all())

        return result.data
```

I have also seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49058269/6086865) which do the same as I need in the database level but I want to do it with `SQLAlchemy`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work? The idea is to load the posts so that `Post.likes` contains only the cases where the current user is the one who has liked the post. `contains_eager('likes')` is supposed to load the `likes` array in `Post`.

```python
# user_id is the id of the current user
q = session.query(Post) \
           .outerjoin(Like, and_(Like.post_id == Post.id,
                                 Like.user_id == user_id)) \
           .options(contains_eager('likes'))
```

Then `is_liked` could be something like `return len(self.likes) > 0`