# Using sql to determine if the user has liked a post

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Use-case.** We have `users` `posts` and `likes` tables. I am a user with `id 4` who wants to get a list of posts and for each individual post I'd like to know if I liked it already or not.

I know this is sounds like a trivial problem, but I can't figure out a simple solution that does not involve using the `union` and the `subquery`..

Consider following data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE posts(
    id bigint NOT null PRIMARY KEY,
    userId bigint NOT NULL references users(id),
    name varchar(40) not null
);

CREATE TABLE likes(
    userId bigint NOT NULL references users(id),
    postId bigint NOT NULL references posts(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(userId, postId)
);

insert into users values (1),(2),(3),(4);

insert into posts values (1, 1, 'Post 1, user 1'), (2, 1, 'Post 2, user 1');
insert into posts values (3, 2, 'Post 3, user 2'), (4, 2, 'Post 4, user 2');
insert into posts values (5, 4, 'Post 5, user 4'), (6, 4, 'Post 6, user 4');

insert into likes values (1, 1), (1, 2);
insert into likes values (2, 1);
insert into likes values (3, 5);
insert into likes values (4, 1), (4, 5);
```

Then, if I want to get the posts that I liked I use (I am user `id=4` in this example)

```
-- get what I like
select 
    p.*
    , true as isLiked
from posts p
left join likes l on l.postId = p.id
where 1=1
    and l.userid = 4
order by p.id;
```

Then, if I want to select the rest of the posts I use:

```
-- get the rest of the posts
select 
    p.*
    ,false as isLiked
from posts p
where 1=1
    and not exists (select 1 from likes l where l.postid = p.id and l.userid = 4)
order by p.id;
```

Finally, the query that accumulates both of these solutions:

```
-- result
select * from (
select 
    p.*
    , true as isLiked
from posts p
left join likes l on l.postId = p.id
where 1=1
    and l.userid = 4
union ALL
select 
    p.*
    ,false as isLiked
from posts p
where 1=1
    and not exists (select 1 from likes l where l.postid = p.id and l.userid = 4)
) p
order by p.id;
```

[image]

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/50108b/1

Back to my question. Is this my imagination or have I overly complicated the query? instead of a single query with a JOIN I ended up with a couple of queries joined in union and a subquery.. Is there a more friendly approach for the task?

I am using `postgresql` of latest version, but of course since it's an `sql` then I guess answers in other languages are just as must welcomed..

**Note:** after I have written the question - `stackoverflow` suggested a topic with a similar question so I was able to solve the problem that way.. The answer is provided below, however, feel free to comment if you have something to say on the subject..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later, following the solution in thread here: [Many-to-many relationship to determine if user has liked a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039856/many-to-many-relationship-to-determine-if-user-has-liked-a-post)

I was able to come up (copy?) with alternative solution that yields the same result:

```
select
    p.*
    ,EXISTS(SELECT * FROM likes l WHERE l.postid = p.id and l.userid = 4) AS isLiked
FROM posts p
order by p.id;
```

While substantially reducing the complexity.

I ran the `explain` command and it does look to perform better on paper.. Not sure if the best solution of all but works fine in my scenario while only a few records in table are present..

Comment: That'll do it! In PostgreSQL that correlated subquery could be `SELECT FROM` instead of `SELECT * FROM` if you want to save a couple of key presses.

Comment: I'd consider those couple of extra key presses as an investment. (Portable SQL.)

Comment: @DavidAldridge it's easier to switch `RDBMS` when your queries are generalized much as possible... but I liked your suggestion anyways :) Truth be told my final query looked like `SELECT 1 FROM likes l WHERE l.postid = p.id and l.userid = 4 LIMIT 1` to address all possible optimizations in the subquery. (I was under the impression that the less fields you are actually selecting the faster the query). Not sure if it's still true for the subquery though. 'Not' according to `explain`..

Comment: No, a decent query optimizer will not access all the columns of the table. It just needs to establish that any matching row exists, so reading the fewest columns possible would be the aim there. In some cases an optimiser can use the presence of constraints on the table to infer that no rows match the condition, and not access the table or indexes at all.